# keyboard changes from numeric to alpha when i try to push textfieldcontroller as a event in streambuilder in flutter 2.5

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final _controller = StreamDataController<TextEditingController>();

var texttype="";
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body:  StreamBuilder<TextEditingController>(
        stream: _controller.stream,
        builder: (context,snapShot){
          return HomeScreen();
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  static final StringBuffer dummyText = StringBuffer();

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   TextEditingController controllerText= TextEditingController(text: HomeScreen.dummyText.toString());

   @override
   void dispose() {
     super.dispose();
     controllerText.dispose();
   }

   //HomeScreen({required Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

          return TextField(
            controller: controllerText,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Enter Text here"
            ),

            onChanged: (String text){
              if((text.length - HomeScreen.dummyText.length).abs() == 3){
                controllerText=TextEditingController(text:text);
                HomeScreen.dummyText.write(text);
                _controller.pushEvent(controllerText);
              }
            },
          );
       // });

  }
}

class StreamDataController<T> {

  final _controller = StreamController<T>();

  Stream<T> get stream => _controller.stream;

  void pushEvent(T event){
    _controller.sink.add(event);
  }


  void dispose(){
    _controller.close();
  }

}
```

any fix for this since i do need to refresh my component by this method just avoid the keyboard shifting from numeric to alpha every  time i try to enter a number.
it is most probably being caused sce i am pushing the controller again in stream builder, else it dosent happen but i want some way to fix this issue. this was working correctly before flutter 2.2.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line to your TextField()

```
TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.number)
```

UPDATED ANSWER (based on the comment)

So if you want I single textfield to accommodate different use cases like for mobile number and email, you can use a selector to select what you'll be entering to the field and condition to choose the input type for the text field.
I will add a small example of how the code will look -

```
enum KeybaordType {number, email}

KeyboardType type;

TextField(keyboardType: type == KeyboardType.number ? TextInputType.number : KeyboardType.email)
```

Comment: I dont want to fix te input type to a specific type
For eg say in case of email text feild this will not be practical

Comment: I did not get you, like if the text field is for entering an email address, then you can set the type to email, I don't get a use case where a single text field is used entering email and number, you can use the different fields for each use cases.